# Petalinux - Multiple Source File application

Tags: c, yocto, xilinx, petalinux

I'm pretty new to the 2020.2 version of Petalinux and I'm trying to create a simple application inside my project using the C template.

After creating the helloworld-app using the command:

```
petalinux-create -t apps --template c --name helloworld-app
```

After enabling the default application and building it successfully,I tried to add some functionality by creating a new directory under *helloworld-app/files* called *Ethernet*, containing 2 files *Etherent.c* and *Ethernet.h*

Finally, I added *the Ethernet.o* object to the list inside the auto-generated Makefile for the module, I also added a VPATH for simplicity.

Unfortunately the build fails, in fact bitbake tells me that no rule for the object Ethernet.o is specified.

1. How can I modify the makefile in order for this simple code to compile?
2. I can edit the *.bb* file? I would like not to, since in that way i would have to specify every src file...

Thank you for the support!
Ethernet.c:

```
#include "Ethernet.h"
//some C code
```

helloworld-app.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Ethernet/Ethernet.h"

//some C code
```

Makefile:

```
APP = helloworld-app

VPATH=Ethernet

# Add any other object files to this list below
APP_OBJS = helloworld-app.o Ethernet.o

all: build

build: $(APP)

$(APP): $(APP_OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(APP_OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
clean:
    rm -f $(APP) *.o
```

Below I included the output of the ***petalinux-build -c helloworld-app*** command:
[image]

Comment: Well my guess is that the `Ethernet.c` source (and header) file should be in some other directory?

Comment: Have you tried setting the object to `Ethernet/Ethernet.o`?

Comment: I also tried using Ethernet/Ethernet.o and the result is the same.

Comment: Is the `Ethernet` directory in the directory of this example project?

Comment: Ethernet/ is at the same level of helloworld-app.c

Comment: `Ethernet.c` and `Ethernet.h` needs to be in the same directory as `helloworld-app.c`.

Comment: I prefer to keep src organized in different directories. Moving the files from Ethernet to the  directory of helloworld-app has no effect

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, but really cumbersome if the number of files increases, is to simply add the path to the source files to the variable SRC_URI inside the .bb file. I will leave this question without an accepted answer, waiting for a more sustainable solution.
Thanks to everyone!